# The Forsaken after Tarmon Gai'don

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light, forsaken

From Wikipedia:

> Moghedien is one of only **two** Forsaken to survive Tarmon Gai'don. [She has an *adam* placed around her neck by a Seanchan *suldam*.]

Also,

> Hessalam is one of only **two** Forsaken to survive Tarmon Gai'don. [She (Graendal) has a compulsion weave backfire and is under Aviendha's control.]

So, that's two. But then there's:

> Egwene finds Mesaana alive in the waking world as "Danelle", but reduced to a childlike state and soiling herself, her mind having been broken. Unable to respond to summons, the Dark One considers her to be dead.

What happens to her after TGS? Does this then make **three** rather than **two**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would venture to say for Mesaana that

> you can't really be considered a Forsaken anymore if you have lost all mental capacities.  I doubt she even remembers who she is anymore.  In this sense, being "alive" simply isn't the same as "surviving".  The person who was Mesaana is dead to the world.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, the only man who could supply us with that information is worm food now. Sanderson could only go on what notes he had, and the rest of it - as unsatisfying as it was - came from his own mind. Now there's a thread worth discussing!